# How to upload data to server from dynamic UI in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

Here in this code I am getting some array value, which is dynamic. On basis of that value I am generating UI. This value may change so according to that UI will change.

Now I have to upload all data on button click to server, I am getting confused.

Like if we have 3 fields static, I can create 3 states and by using that I can pass that value to the API.

But here as I am generating dynamic UI how can I take value and upload.

Below is the array value on basis of that I am generating dynamic form.

```
     formFields: Array(8)
        0:
        key: "dateOfBirth"
        label: "Date of Birth"
        model: "model.dateOfBirth"
        name: "dateOfBirth"
        placeHolder: "DD/MM/YYYY"
        position: "1"
        required: "true"
        type: "date"
        __typename: "FormFields"
        __proto__: Object
        1:
        key: "lastRechargedAmount"
        label: "Last RCC Amt."
        model: "model.lastRechargedAmount"
        name: "lastRechargedAmount"
        placeHolder: "Amount in Naira"
        position: "2"
        required: "false"
        type: "text"
        __typename: "FormFields"
        __proto__: Object
        2:
        key: "stateOfOrigin"
        label: "State of Origin"
        model: "model.stateOfOrigin"
        name: "stateOfOrigin"
        placeHolder: "State of origin"
        position: "3"
        required: "true"
        type: "parentSelect"
        __typename: "FormFields"
        __proto__: Object
        3: {type: "childSelect", model: "model.lgaOfOrigin", label: "LGA of Origin", placeHolder: "Enter Lga of origin", key: "lgaOfOrigin", …}
        4:
        key: "frequentlyDialledNumbers1"
        label: "Freq.Dialled No"
        model: "model.frequentlyDialledNumbers"
        name: "frequentlyDialledNumbers1"
        placeHolder: "frequently dialled MSISDN"
        position: "5"
        required: "true"
        type: "text"
        __typename: "FormFields"
        __proto__: Object
        5: {type: "text", model: "model.frequentlyDialledNumbers", label: "Freq.Dialled No", placeHolder: "frequently dialled MSISDN", key: "frequentlyDialledNumbers2", …}
        6: {type: "text", model: "model.frequentlyDialledNumbers", label: "Freq.Dialled No", placeHolder: "frequently dialled MSISDN", key: "frequentlyDialledNumbers3", …}
        7: {type: "text", model: "model.frequentlyDialledNumbers", label: "Freq.Dialled No", placeHolder: "frequently dialled MSISDN", key: "frequentlyDialledNumbers4", …}
        length: 8
```

The code below I am using to generate UI and on button press I am calling function validatUser(). On button press I have to take all values and send in this function.

```
    class CustomerEvalidation extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const { eValidationMasterData } = this.props;
        this.state = {
          selectedRow: -1,
          disableBtn: true,
          showSimSwapReason: false,
          dateOfBirth: currentDate,
          lastName: '',
          lgaValue: eValidationMasterData.masterData.lga[0].code,
          stateValue: eValidationMasterData.masterData.lga[0].state.name,
          stateCode: eValidationMasterData.masterData.lga[0].state.code,
          isModalVisible:false
        };
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        this.setState({
          showSimSwapReason: false
        });
      }

      lgaChanged = (key, val) => {
        this.handleChangeLga({ field: "lgaValue" }, val);
      };

      handleChangeLga = (props, e) => {
        const { lga } = this.props.eValidationMasterData.masterData;
        let tempObj = this.state.lgaValue;
        for (let i = 0; lga[i]; i++) {
          if (lga[i].code == e) {
            const stateData = lga[i].state;
            this.setState({
              stateValue: stateData.name,
              stateCode: stateData.code
            })
          }
        }
        tempObj[props.field] = e;
        this.setState({ lgaValue: e });
      };

      validatUser = () => {
        const {dateOfBirth,lgaValue,stateCode}=this.state;
        const validateUser = {
          dateOfBirth: dateOfBirth,
          lgaValue:lgaValue,
          stateCode:stateCode

        }
        this.props.verifySecurityQuestions(validateUser);
      }
      onChangeExp = (e) => {
        this.setState({
          dateOfBirth: e
        })
    }
      render() {
        const { dateOfBirth, lastName, lgaValue, stateValue } = this.state;
        const { isCamera, loading, error, securityQuestions, eValidationMasterData,validateUser } = this.props;
        const { formFields } = securityQuestions.evalidatorType[0].SelectionList[0];
        const { lga } = eValidationMasterData.masterData;
        let lgaOptions = [];
        lga.map(({ code: value, name: label }) => {
          lgaOptions.push({ value, label });
        });

        return (
          <View style={{minHeight: deviceHeight, color:'#fff'}}>
            {loading &&
              <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <OverlaySpinner color="#00678F" />
              </View>}
            {!isCamera && (
              <View style={styles.container}>
                {formFields.map((document, index) => {
                  return (
                    <View style={{backgroundColor: '#fff' }}
                      key={index}>
                      {document.type === 'text' && (
                        <View style={{ padding: 15}} >
                          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
                            <SmallText textColor="grey" text={document.label} />
                          </View>
                          <Item style={{ borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth: 1, marginLeft: 0 }}>
                            <Input
                              value={lastName}
                              keyboardType='default'
                              onChangeText={(lastName) =>
                                this.setState({ lastName: lastName.replace(/\s/g, '') })}
                            />
                          </Item>
                        </View>
                      )
                      }

                      {document.type === 'date' && (
                        <View  style={{ padding: 15}}>
                          <View style={{
                            flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#fff'
                          }}>
                            <SmallText textColor="grey" text={document.label} />
                          </View>
                          <Item style={{ borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth: 1, marginLeft: 0 }}>
                            <DatePicker
                              minDate={minDate}
                              maxDate={currentDate}
                              currentDate={dateOfBirth}
                              format={format}
                              width={deviceWidth}
                              onChange={(dateOfBirth) => this.onChangeExp(dateOfBirth)}
                              marginLeft={0}
                            />
                          </Item>
                        </View>
                      )}

                    </View>
                  );
                }
                )}

              </View>
            )}
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', padding: 15 }}>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', flex:1 }}>
                <SelectField options={lgaOptions} value={lgaValue}
                  onChange={this.lgaChanged} that={this}
                  label={"LGA of Origin"} />
              </View>


              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
                  <SmallText textColor="grey" text={"State of Origin"} />
                </View>
                <Item style={{ borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth: 1, marginLeft: 0 }}>
                  <Input
                    value={stateValue}
                    keyboardType='default'
                    onChangeText={(stateValue) =>
                      this.setState({ stateValue: stateValue.replace(/\s/g, '') })}
                  />
                </Item>
              </View>

              <View style={{ paddingBottom: 15, marginTop: 20 }}>
                <PrimaryBtn label={'Validate User'} disabled={false}
                  onPress={() => this.validatUser()} />
              </View>
            </View>


          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    export default CustomerEvalidation;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check my SupplierForm example hope you will get a lots of information

Constant data

```
"formFields": [{
            "id": "1",
            "name": "companyname",
            "label": "Company name",
            "type": "input",
            "placeholder": "",
            "returnKeyType": "go"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "supplier_type",
            "label": "Supplier type",
            "type": "drop_down"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "country",
            "label": "Country",
            "type": "drop_down"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "phonenumber",
            "label": "Mobile number",
            "type": "input",
            "placeholder": "",
            "returnKeyType": "next"
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "name": "phonenumber1",
            "label": "Landline number",
            "type": "input",
            "placeholder": "",
            "returnKeyType": "next"
        },
        {
            "id": "6",
            "name": "email",
            "label": "Email / UserID",
            "type": "input",
            "placeholder": "",
            "returnKeyType": "next"
        },
        {
            "id": "7",
            "name": "contact_person",
            "label": "Contact person",
            "type": "input",
            "placeholder": "",
            "returnKeyType": "next"
        },
        {
            "id": "8",
            "name": "skype_id",
            "label": "Skype id",
            "type": "input",
            "placeholder": "",
            "returnKeyType": "next"
        },
        {
            "id": "9",
            "name": "notes",
            "label": "Notes",
            "type": "input",
            "placeholder": "",
            "returnKeyType": "go"
        }
    ]
```

SupplierForm component

```
// @flow

import * as React from 'react';
import { Div, Button, InputText, DropDown } from '../../materialComponents';
import data from '../../constantData/supplier';

/* flow types
============================================================================= */
type Props = {
  action: string,
  editData?: ?{
    companyname: string,
    supplier_type_id: number | string,
    country: number | string,
    phonenumber: string,
    phonenumber1: string,
    landlord_email: string,
    contact_person: string,
    landlord_skype_id: string,
    notes: string,
  },
  data: Object,
  buttonLoader: boolean,
  onSubmit: (data: Object) => any,
  onError: (type: string, msg: string) => any,
};
type State = {
  companyname: string,
  supplier_type_id: number | string,
  country_id: number | string,
  phonenumber: string,
  phonenumber1: string,
  email: string,
  contact_person: string,
  skype_id: string,
  notes: string,
};

/* ============================================================================
  <SupplierForm />
============================================================================= */
class SupplierForm extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  static defaultProps = { editData: null };

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      companyname: '',
      supplier_type_id: 0,
      country_id: 0,
      phonenumber: '',
      phonenumber1: '',
      email: '',
      contact_person: '',
      skype_id: '',
      notes: '',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { editData, action } = this.props;
    if (action === 'edit') {
      const record = { ...editData };
      const {
        companyname,
        supplier_type_id,
        country,
        phonenumber,
        phonenumber1,
        landlord_email,
        contact_person,
        landlord_skype_id,
        notes,
      } = record;
      this.setState({
        companyname,
        supplier_type_id,
        country_id: country,
        phonenumber,
        phonenumber1,
        email: landlord_email,
        contact_person,
        skype_id: landlord_skype_id,
        notes,
      });
    }
  }

  // for submit form
  _handleSubmit = () => {
    const { onError, onSubmit } = this.props;
    const {
      companyname,
      supplier_type_id,
      country_id,
      phonenumber,
      phonenumber1,
      email,
      contact_person,
      skype_id,
      notes,
    } = this.state;
    const supplier = {
      companyname,
      supplier_type_id,
      country_id,
      phonenumber,
      phonenumber1,
      email,
      contact_person,
      skype_id,
      notes,
    };
    if (!companyname) {
      onError('error', 'Please Enter Company Name');
    } else if (!Number(supplier_type_id)) {
      onError('error', 'Please Select Supplier Type');
    } else if (!Number(supplier_type_id)) {
      onError('error', 'Please Select Country');
    } else if (!email) {
      onError('error', 'Please Enter Email');
    } else {
      onSubmit(supplier);
    }
  };

  /**
   * handle picker values
   * @param {string} fieldName
   * @param {string} value
   */
  _handlePickerValue = (pickerName: string, _id: string) => {
    this.setState({
      [`${pickerName}_id`]: _id,
    });
  };

  /**
   * handle input values
   * @param {string} fieldName
   * @param {string} value
   */
  _handleInputValue = (fieldName: string, value: string) => {
    this.setState({ [fieldName]: value });
  };

  /**
   * render the all input fields
   * @param {Object}  dropDownData
   */
  _renderInputFields = (dropDownData: Object) => {
    const { formFields } = data;

    return formFields.map(field => {
      if (field.type === 'input') {
        return (
          <InputText
            key={field.id}
            label={field.label}
            value={this.state[field.name]}
            onChangeText={value => this._handleInputValue(field.name, value)}
            reference={input => {
              // $FlowFixMe
              this[`${field.name}_ref`] = input;
            }}
            returnKeyType={field.returnKeyType}
            // $FlowFixMe
            onSubmitEditing={() => this[`${field.name}_ref`].focus()}
          />
        );
      }
      if (field.type === 'drop_down') {
        const itemData =
          field.name === 'country'
            ? dropDownData.countries
            : dropDownData[`${field.name}s`];
        const selectedValue = this.state[`${field.name}_id`];
        return (
          <DropDown
            key={field.id}
            label={field.label}
            data={itemData}
            selectedValue={selectedValue}
            onChange={value => this._handlePickerValue(field.name, value)}
          />
        );
      }
      return null;
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { data: dropDownData, buttonLoader, action } = this.props;
    const buttonTitle = action === 'add' ? 'Save' : 'Update';
    return (
      <Div>
        {this._renderInputFields(dropDownData)}
        <Button
          loader={buttonLoader}
          color="#FFFFFF"
          backgroundColor="#21A24F"
          marginVertical={10}
          borderRadius={2}
          iconName="save"
          title={buttonTitle}
          onPress={this._handleSubmit}
        />
      </Div>
    );
  }
}

/* export
============================================================================= */
export default SupplierForm;
```

Comment: Thanks .. I was confused ,that  I am generating all text boxes dynamically ,and it will change all time , so how can I get data and submit..

Comment: First you will have to define default state for all input field then change the specific input field using onChange and then use the state data while submitting the form. Please check the my example

Comment: ok I am looking on your code only.. but one thing how can I define default states ,where i don't know how many input fields will come in array, And on button press I have to take all data in one object. I use GraphQL

Comment: you can use the default state as formData = {}; then add properties to it. like this.setState({formData[propertyName] : value})

Answer (score 0):

sorry, i'm a lazy coder .... i'll try to answer AbriefAP . . .

state is not the only option to hold variables, use/create object and push values there;

```
var obj1={};

_on_fld_change(document,v){
obj1[document.name]=v;
}

_on_submit(){
return fetch(URL,'POST',{obj1})
}

render(){
...
return(
..
<Comp onValueChange={(v)=>this._on_fld_change(document,v)}/>

)
}
```